# How can you remove the table-tags in CreateUserWizard control

Tags: asp.net, .net, css, createuserwizard

How can I use the CreateUserWizard control without having it render html tables?

I've customized the layout of the CreateUserWizard, and I'm using css to style it. My button is too far away from my form, due to the `<table>` tags asp.net is rendering by default.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="cphContent_CreateUserWizard1" style="border-collapse: collapse; ">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height: 100%; ">
            <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; ">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="height: 100%; width: 100%; ">
                                <fieldset>
                                    ...
                                </fieldset>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to stop ASP.NET CreateUserWizard from adding tables into HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390520/is-there-a-way-to-stop-asp-net-createuserwizard-from-adding-tables-into-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can not remove the table-tag from the control because the control is formatted this way.

Comment: Are there any alternatives that perform a similar function that don't render tables or can be configured not to?

Answer (score 2):

The CreateUserWizard doesn't have the RenderOuterTable property, but you can remove the table by using a LayoutTemplate and PlaceHolders (just like the ListView control).

This is an example:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="1"> 
  <LayoutTemplate> 
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="WizardStepPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="navigationPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
  </LayoutTemplate> 

  <HeaderTemplate>
    Header 
  </HeaderTemplate> 

  <StepNavigationTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="MovePrevious" Text="Previous" ID="StepPreviousButton">Previous</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="NextLinkButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext">Next</asp:LinkButton>
  </StepNavigationTemplate>

  <WizardSteps> 
    <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server"> 
      <ContentTemplate> 
      </ContentTemplate> 
    </asp:CreateUserWizardStep> 

    <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server"> 
      <ContentTemplate> 
      </ContentTemplate> 
    </asp:CreateUserWizardStep> 
  </WizardSteps> 
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Comment: I had problems with the `HeaderTemplate`. Just using the `LayoutTemplate` with the two placeholders as shown was enogh for me to get rid of the outer table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from design view and have visual studio generate the markup into template you can modify. In design view, click on the createUserWizard control, click on the angle bracket (`>`) at the top-right corner, then click `Customize Create User Step`. Switch to code and edit the markup to taste!!

[image]

Comment: I did that, but it still automatically starts and ends the table.

Comment: Can you fix the broken image link in your answer?

Comment: This works, with one caveat: I can not make it work with my resx files. I either use the explicitly generated texts or leaves the labels emtpy.