# Is there a way to stop ASP.NET CreateUserWizard from adding tables into HTML?

Tags: asp.net, html, w3c-validation

How can I remove the html `<table>` elements that are generated by the CreateUserWizard to validate the login page against HTML 5?

I've managed to get my entire site to validate to HTML 5, except for 3 errors caused by the CreateUserWizard in my login page.

This is the code that causes the errors, which I can't seem to stop from being generated:

```
<table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CreateUserWizard1">
<tr style="height:100%;">
    <td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height:100%;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td style="height:100%;width:100%;">
```

Comment: To customize the user account creation step, create a <ContentTemplate> element http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178342.ASPX

Comment: @kobe Thanks, I did that earlier and was able to remove the majority of the table elements, but the code I posted above still generates and even with the ContentTemplate I can't see it anywhere other than when I view source in my browser.

Comment: can you use jQuery in your page?

Comment: @kobe Yes as long as it doesn't impact on WCAG validation

Answer (score 1):

with jquery:

```
$('table').replaceWith( $('table').html()
   .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div id='table'")
   .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div")
   .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
   .replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
   .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
   .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
);
```

or, you can try
https://github.com/ryandoom/jquery-plugin-table-to-div